# Task in Airflow with DockerSwarmOperator keeps in running state

Tags: airflow, docker-swarm

I have a task in airflow that uses a DockerSwarmOperator to run a short-lived container. Once the container finished execution with no errors (DESIRED STATE: Shutdown) , the task in Airflow keeps in "Running" state forever...  Pls advise. Thanks!

Server: Oracle Linux 9
Airflow 2.4.2
Docker running in a linux server

````
    start_dag = DummyOperator(
        task_id='start_dag'
        )
    end_dag = DummyOperator(
        task_id='end_dag'
        )
    hop = DockerSwarmOperator(
        task_id='Job_exec_HOP',
        image='apache/hop',
        api_version='auto',
        auto_remove=True,
        environment= {
            'HOP_RUN_PARAMETERS': 'INPUT_DIR=',
            'HOP_LOG_LEVEL': 'Basic',
            'HOP_FILE_PATH': '${PROJECT_HOME}/J01_BIT_DW_VENTAS_NAVEGADOR.hwf',
            'HOP_PROJECT_FOLDER': '/files/INDUTOP_BI_ETL',
            'HOP_PROJECT_NAME': 'INDUTOP_BI_ETL',
            'HOP_SHARED_JDBC_FOLDER': '/files/JDBC_FOLDER',
            'HOP_RUN_CONFIG': 'local'
        },
        docker_url="unix://var/run/docker.sock",
        network_mode="bridge",
        mounts=[Mount(source='/mnt/hop_bi_etl/hopdata', target='/files', type='bind')],
        force_pull=False
        )

start_dag >> hop >> end_dag ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's known bug in [DockerSwarmOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/28452): You need to set `enable_loging` to `False`.